# how to echo a array value with single quotes

Tags: php

Am trying to echo an array variable with the single quotes around.

The below should echo `'09878554'` where `$dval['A']='09878554'`.

This is what am trying to do below:

```
echo '$dval['A']';
```

Comment: -> `echo "'" . $dval["A"] . "'";`

Comment: You can't do that. Strings inside single quotes are simply strings and are not evaluated. So you could try `echo "'{$dval['A']}'";`

Comment: can you share what your reason for using single quotes is? Double quotes are more of a standard as far as I know, as it sidesteps this sort of syntax muddling.

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate the value with the quotes.
`echo "'" . $dval['A'] . "'"`

You can also visually simplify the code by assigning the array value to another variable like this:

```php
$variable = $dval['A'];
echo "'" . $variable . "'";
```

Comment: Thanks all.I assigned it to a variable and echoed it